# Cannot connect to Internet unless I disable then enable interface (since upgrade to 15.04)

Tags: networking, internet, connection-sharing

My computer has two network cards:
- eth0 has a static IP address and connects to the LAN. It is not managed by NetworkManager.
- eth1 has a dynamic address and connects to my cable modem.
The Internet connection is shared with other computers on the LAN.

Ever since upgrading from Xubuntu 14.10 to 15.04, I must:

$ sudo ifconfig eth0 down # yes, the one with the static IP address for the LAN
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 up

in order to connect to the Internet (on this or any computer).

According to ifconfig, eth1 gets the expected IP address and DNS servers, but if I ping by name or number it just sits there until I kill it.

How do I fix this?